# phpmailer timeout not working

Tags: php, phpmailer

i use phpmailer to send mail,and i want to get the result,because send mail  is very frequently. so i want to use phpmailer "timeout" .but is not working.
my code

```
        $mail             = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Timeout  =   10;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port       = 465;
    $mail->Username   = "qinqin1920@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password   = "xxxx";
    $mail->From       = "qinqin1920@gmail.com";
    $mail->Subject    = "This is the subject";
    $mail->AltBody    = "test";
    //$mail->WordWrap   = 50; // set word wrap
    $mail->MsgHTML("test233");
    //$mail->AddReplyTo("qinqin1920@gmail.com");
    $mail->AddAddress("xxxx@qq.com");

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    echo "<br/>".time()."<br/>";
    echo "time out is ".$mail->Timeout."<br/>";
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message has been";
    }
    echo "<br/>".time()."<br/>";
```

and echo is :
1383181520   time out is 10      Message has been      1383181534

can you help me

Comment: *"and echo is : 1383181520 time out is 10 Message has been 1383181534"* - Help with what? Seems like it's doing its job. Maybe the time format isn't what you're expecting. What "are" you expecting in fact?

Comment: Note: The default Timeout in more current versions of PHPMailer is 300 seconds = 5 minutes. I also had a version from 2014 that used a timeout of 10 minutes by default. Took a while to track that down...

Answer (score 9):

The [documentation](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/wp/wp-includes/PHPMailer.class.html#det_fields_Timeout) states that "var $Timeout = 10 Sets the SMTP server timeout in seconds" and "this function will not work with the win32 version."

If you want a longer timeout value, simply set it to a minute (60 seconds) or so.  If you are sending multiple emails through the same SMTP server, it may be beneficial to [keep the connection open](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/wp/wp-includes/PHPMailer.class.html#det_fields_SMTPKeepAlive), but then remember to close it at the end.

If you do extend the timeout, also make sure that you increase the [time limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) on the script, or remove it all together:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0); // remove a time limit if not in safe mode
    // OR
    set_time_limit(120); // set the time limit to 120 seconds

    $mail                = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Timeout       =   60; // set the timeout (seconds)
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // don't close the connection between messages
    // ...
    // Send email(s)
    $mail->SmtpClose(); // close the connection since it was left open.
?>
```