# phpMailer doesn't timeout after given time

Tags: php, timeout, phpmailer

```
$mailer = new SMTP;    
$mailer->Timeout = 5;    
$mailer->connect($host, $port)
```

This should cancel the connect() after 5 seconds, but the timeout takes much longer and don't cancel after 5 seconds.

How can I force my script to stop trying connect to the SMTP after 5 seconds?

I'm looking forward for your answers.

Best regards,

distractedGuy

Comment: same question asked here check this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696720/phpmailer-timeout-not-working

Comment: @tzafar Thank you for this link. I have seen this question, but unfortunately there is no helpful answer and the question was made 1 year ago.

Comment: their is one main point if you are using windows then it will not work (this function will not work with the win32 version) as in documents

Comment: @tzafar Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use phpMailer on CentOs 6.5 x64, so it's not the win32 version, therefore there is unfortunately no helpful answer for me in the other question. I even can't vote or add any comment to it, because I'm a new user.

Answer (score 7):

There are two timeouts in PHPMailer's SMTP class - `Timeout` and `Timelimit`.

`Timeout` applies when making the initial TCP connection. `Timelimit` is the duration allowed for each SMTP command's response. Both default to 5 minutes (in accordance with the RFCs) - so it could be that you are connecting quickly, but then the server is very slow to respond to commands. You should try setting the `Timelimit` to a lower value like this:

```
$mail->getSMTPInstance()->Timelimit = 5;
```

All of this should serve to remind you that SMTP is not intended to be an interactive, immediate protocol, so you should only be using SMTP to a nearby server that can queue your request properly.